# I get a weird behavior when I test my in-app purchase of type subscription

Tags: swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to add my very first `in-app purchase` of type `renewable subscription` in a SwiftUI app and I get a weird behavior. I actually don't know if it's me or just a normal/weird behavior. Let me explain the problem.

The first thing I do is to initialize the `StoreManager class` and then inject it into the environment:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct BootcampApp: App {
    @StateObject private var storeManager = StoreManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(storeManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the second thing I do is to check, with the `load() function`, if the user is a premium (paid) one or not:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var storeManager: StoreManager
    @AppStorage("isPremium") private var isPremium = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            FirstView()
            SecondView()
        }
        .task { await load() }
    }

    private func load() async {
        guard let subscription = storeManager.subscriptions.first else { return }
        isPremium = (try? await storeManager.isPurchased(subscription)) ?? isPremium
    }
}
```

For the record, I'm actually using a `storekit file` on my Xcode project linked to the `StoreKit Configuration in the Scheme`.

And, everything works very well, excepts that some time `isPremium` becomes `false` for absolutely no reason. So, I don't know if it's my `load() function` or just something very common when we use a `storekit file` instead of a real product from the App Store Connect.

Also, here's the `isPurchased function`. It's very basic as I don't check his state but only his presence on `purchasedSubscription`.

```
func isPurchased(_ product: Product) async throws -> Bool {
    return purchasedSubscriptions.contains(product)
}
```

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Probably a timing issue, `isPurchased` isn't really eating for the products tote loaded. Just a guess

Comment: You think that the problem can be because the `StoreManager class` doesn't have enough time to be correctly initialized? I could maybe try to add a `DispatchQueue.main.async()` or something.

Comment: Don’t mix GCD and async/await, look into an actor. Dispatch queue would likely not make a difference anyway, it still isn’t waiting.

Comment: Well, after many attempts I still have this weird behavior. I'm just stuck.

Comment: I FOUND IT. There is instead a limited number of renewals! It's said on App Store Connect: "Choose a renewal frequency to speed up or slow down how often subscriptions will renew for this tester in the Sandbox environment. Subscriptions will automatically terminate after 12 renewals."